# Eslint Configuration ecma version

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

If I run

```
eslint --init
```

configuration wizard runs and I get **.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest"
  },
  "rules": {}
}
```

In the file, **env** is set to **es2021** but the syntax is **ecmaVersion latest**

Should these both fields have equal ecma versions or not? Can a conflict arise by this configuration?

Comment: <https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-parser-options>, third paragraph.

Comment: the latest ecma is es2024 but the configuration sets it to es2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading what the official documentation states in the [Specifying Environments](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-environments) section

> es2021 - adds all ECMAScript 2021 globals **and automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 12**.

and what states in the [Specifying Parser Options](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-parser-options) section

> By the same token, supporting ES6 syntax is not the same as supporting new ES6 globals (e.g., new types such as Set). For ES6 syntax, use { "parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 6 } }; for new ES6 global variables, use { "env": { "es6": true } }. Setting { "env": { "es6": true } } enables ES6 syntax automatically, but { "parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 6 } } does not enable ES6 globals automatically. In summary, to support only ES6 syntax, use { "parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 6 } }, and to support both ES6 syntax and new ES6 global variables, such as Set and others, use { "env": { "es6": true } }.

I would say that you should omit the "ecmaVersion" property if you want to support es2021 globals and syntax only without occurring in any possible issues.

Comment: Thanks why do they add the parserOptions in default json if it is redundant?

Comment: I think to let you know you can change it or just to always allow you use the latest ecma version synthax regarless of the globals you are using. I have also found this discussion https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/15166